# How to import multiple Excel files to a single Google Sheet spreadsheet without creating intermediate files?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have several Excel files in a shared Google Drive.

I want to import their content inside a single Google Sheet spreadsheet.

I found [this sample code](https://spreadsheet.dev/automatically-convert-excel-spreadsheets-to-google-sheets-using-apps-script) and tried to adapt it to my use case.

Here is my implementation for a single test file :

```
function importFile() {
  // Log the name of every file in the user's Drive.
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("myFolderName")

  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    files = folders.next().getFiles()
  } else {
    return null
  }

  var file = files.next();
  Logger.log(file.getName());

  let spreadsheetId = convertExcelToGoogleSheets(file.getName())
}

function convertExcelToGoogleSheets(fileName) {
  let files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);

  let excelFile = null;
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    excelFile = files.next();
  } else {
    return null;
  }

  let blob = excelFile.getBlob();

  let config = {
    title: "[Google Sheets] " + excelFile.getName(),
    parents: [{ id: excelFile.getParents().next().getId() }],
    mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
  };

  Logger.log(config);

  let spreadsheet = Drive.Files.insert(config, blob);
  return spreadsheet.id;
}
```

This however crashes :

```
3:50:45 PM  Notice  Execution started
3:50:46 PM  Info    2021_Salariés appartenant à une entreprise extérieure.xlsx
3:50:46 PM  Info    {parents=[{id=1mxYU55TOX1gp2ABzmSpB_lEWSw2FGa7v}], mimeType=application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet, title=[Google Sheets] 2021_Salariés appartenant à une entreprise extérieure.xlsx}
3:50:47 PM  Error   
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.insert failed with error: File not found: 1mxYU55TOX1gp2ABzmSpB_lEWSw2FGa7v
convertExcelToGoogleSheets  @ Code.gs:37
importFile  @ Code.gs:14
```

The error message comes from the `Drive.Files.insert(config, blob);` instruction. I think this is because the app script refuses to create the file in a shared folder.

Anyway, I have tens of very short Excel files that I want to read and concatenate in a single Sheet, So I don't think creating that many intermediate Sheet files is efficient.

Is it possible to directly convert the blob to a Google Sheet without creating a new file?

Comment: If you want to improve efficiency I see two options: to use Sheets API (it should work a little bit faster) or to download the sheets in a local folder and to process them with a Python script (probably Node.js etc could be used as well).

Comment: I'd rather use the Sheet API... But does it work directly on Excel files? I think I need to convert the xlsx files to Google Sheet first... Which is were I'm stuck

Comment: No, Sheets API will do about the same: convert every XLSX file into a temporary Google Spreadsheet, take data from the temporary spreadsheet, append the data to the main spreadsheet, remove the temporary spreadsheet, etc. It just should work a little bit faster (not sure how much will the difference, though). But if you have dozens or hundreds files: a local script could be a preferable option.

Comment: So what question you're asking after all? '_Is it possible to directly convert the blob to a Google Sheet without creating a new file?_' — the answer is 'No'. You show the code, and you say it doesn't work because the shared folder. Have you tried to run it on another folder? Is it work at all?

Comment: I have 2 questions. 1. About `I think this is because the app script refuses to create the file in a shared folder.`, in this case, is the folder id a folder in a Shared Drive? If my understanding is correct, do you have permission for writing to Shared Drive? 2. About `Is it possible to directly convert the blob to a Google Sheet without creating a new file?`, in your showing script, I think that the Blob of XLSX is directly converted to Google Spreadsheet. So, can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: The answer provided by Cooper is exactly what I want to do... Except it does not work because the `SpreadsheetApp.openById` method doesn't work with Excel files. Yes, I tried in my drive and it worked. It does not on the shared drive though. And yes, I do have the permissions to write in the shared drive

Comment: You can not open XLSX with `SpreadsheetApp.openById`, first you need to build a temporary file like you did with `Drive.Files.insert( ... )` this is mandatory to access content. About this function, you mention an error. Could you check the folder ID are the same between your log and in Google Drive? Note: Click on folder > get link, and select like this `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/[HERE IS YOUR ID]?usp=sharing`

Answer (score 2):

Try import this way:

```
function importFile() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0")
  const folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("myFolderName");
  let fA = [];
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    let files = folders.next().getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      let file = files.next()
      fA.push([file.getName(),file.getId()])
    }
  } 
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 1,fA.length,fA[0].length).setValues(fA);

}
```

Try something like this:

Note I did not test this and I'm not going to.

```
function importFile() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0")
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("myFolderName");
  let fA = [];
  let dA = [];
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    let files = folders.next().getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      let file = files.next();
      let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
      ss.getSheets().forEach(sh => {
        dA.push(sh.getDataRange().getValues())
      })

      fA.push([file.getName(),file.getId()])
    }
  } 
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 1,fA.length,fA[0].length).setValues(fA);
  dA.forEach(a => {
    dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, a.length, a[0].length).setValues(a);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  })

}
```

If it doesn't work figure it out for yourself

Comment: I'm sorry, but this copies the name and Id of my Excel files into a Google Sheet. I need to copy the content of the Excel files, not just their names and ids

Comment: I understand that but it's an improvement over what you were doing.